# opendaylight REST API

Tags: opendaylight

I downloaded latest version of ODL 15. I entered to the karaf interface.
as given in https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-phosphorus/developer-guides/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html

I access to http://myip:8181/index.html from my browser

But It returned:

HTTP ERROR 401

Problem accessing /index.html. Reason:

Unauthorized

i tried to install features like odl-mdsal-apidocs, but not able to. giving error "Error executing command: No matching features for odl-mdsal-apidocs"

What should I do?

Comment: Port 8181 is not open. what is the procedure to open the port

Answer (score 0):

new releases from odl doesn't support dlux which is the gui of OpenDayLight

you can fix it by using older release like carbon